# python json remove() element issue for a while condition

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file in the following format. What I need to do is to get rid of the whole dictionary of elements where the "URI" does not contain "http"

```
[
{
    "Exchange Name": "Standard & Poor's Indices",
    "Number": 33.0,
    "URI": "http://us.spindices.com/documents/additional-material/spdji-fixed-income-calendar-2016.xlsx",
    "ref_id": "33_Standard_&_Poor's_Indices"
},
{
    "Exchange Name": "ISE Mercury",
    "Number": 36.0,
    "URI": "follow OPRA",
    "ref_id": "36_ISE_Mercury"
},
{
    "Exchange Name": "Aequitas Neo",
    "Number": 37.0,
    "URI": "email for holidays",
    "ref_id": "37_Aequitas_Neo"
},
{
    "Exchange Name": "FINRA SPDS 144A",
    "Number": 38.0,
    "URI": "https://www.finra.org/industry/trace/trace-holiday-calendar",
    "ref_id": "38_FINRA_SPDS_144A"
}
]
```

So far I have stuck with the following function. Here the problem is that remove() does not actually remove a 'URI' element from the string. But after I run the code for the second time, it works. I think I need to use a while loop for this, but how do I implement it in this setting.

```
def sys_validate_data():
    with open('./data_out/uniq_set.json') as jf:
        json_decoded = json.load(jf)
        for ix in json_decoded:
            if "http" not in ix["URI"]:
                json_decoded.remove(ix)

        with open('./data_out/uniq_set.json', 'w') as fpw:
            json.dump(list(json_decoded), fpw, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: Not again. Do *not* remove/add/alter a list (and any other collection) while you are iterating over it.

Comment: as above states, when you are iterating over a list and altering the count of the objects, you break the loop that keeps track of how many iterations it needs to do and this can cause exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem. This gave me a chance to actually go through list comprehension again. For anyone in the future here's a good tutorial: http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ 

In gist, a list comprehension will be formatted as,
list_name = [expression; loop, condition]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify a list while iterating over it. Doing so can produce unexpected behavior. Instead, you can use a list comprehension to filter elements from your JSON list:

```
def sys_validate_data():
    with open('./data_out/uniq_set.json') as jf:
        json_decoded = [ix for ix in json.load(jf) if "http" in ix["URI"]]
        ....
```

Comment: I guess he meant only URIs starting with http. However, for his wording ('containing http') this is correct.

Comment: :D we wrote a comment about that at the same time

Comment: Note that `in` implicity does a substring search in this case. So you may accidentally leave out some false positives, depending on OP's wording.

Comment: Jeez, three comments within a minute about this! That's kinda awesome.

Comment: @Igle Yes, your right. Like I said, it was a trivial nitpick. Your answer will still work.

Comment: @JoshuaRLi Right. But unless the OP specifics otherwise my answer is based off of him saying 'containing http' rather than 'starting with http'.

Comment: Thanks everyone and @ChristianDean. List comprehension is the answer.

Comment: @SamSal glad to here that. If this answer helped you, consider accepting it by clicking the checkmar next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension and don't alter a list while iterating:

```
validated_json = [entry for entry in json_decoded if entry['URI'].startswith('http')]
```

Extended example:

```
def sys_validate_data():
    with open('./data_out/uniq_set.json') as jf:
        json_decoded = json.load(jf)
        validated_json = [entry for entry in json_decoded if entry['URI'].startswith('http')]

        with open('./data_out/uniq_set.json', 'w') as fpw:
            json.dump(validated_json, fpw, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: Small nitpick: He said remove the element if it didn't contain `"http"` not if it didn't start with `"http"`. So you should probably use `in` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Igle.  Regarding "http", 'startswith' or 'in' any will do for me on this one. Although the best practice is always regex.